# How to override image on JLabel in ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a program that displays 3 random images on JLabels. When I click a button `"Change"`, the program will display 3 images, replacing the original images. I'm having trouble figuring out how to replace the originals with the new ones. I've tried copying parts of the code to override the original but I'm not sure why the images don't change when I press the button. Here's the action code I have so far:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    String eventName = event.getActionCommand();
    if (eventName.equals ("Swap")) {         

        JLabel img1, img2, img3;

        int[] num = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}; //the next few lines are part of the file names
        char[] name = {'c', 'd', 'h', 's'};
        String[] imgs = new String[5];

        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
            int a = (int)(Math.random()*12);
            int b = (int)(Math.random()*4);

            imgs[i] = Integer.toString(num[a]) + name[b] + ".gif";
        }

        ImageIcon one = new ImageIcon(imgs[0]);
        ImageIcon two = new ImageIcon(imgs[1]);
        ImageIcon three = new ImageIcon(imgs[2]);

        img1 = new JLabel(one);
        img2 = new JLabel(two);
        img3 = new JLabel(three);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel.add(img1);
        panel.add(img2);
        panel.add(img3);

    }
```

How can I replace the images by pressing the button?

Comment: You're creating a new JPanel and new JLabels you need to **change the original ones** instead. We'll need to see more code to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble figuring out how to replace the originals with the new ones.

Don't keep creating new components.

Instead update the components that are currently visible on the frame using:

```
label1.setIcon(...);
```

repeat for the other labels that you created in the constructor of your class.